# Datetime.parseExact gives (1-9) day's value with single digit, without 0

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this code, it gives day's value as 1,2,3 .. instead of 01,02,03..

```
(DateTime.ParseExact("20160416", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

gives:  `4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM.`

I need `04/16/2016 12:00:00 AM`

I have tried different cultures but nothing worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't store any formatting information, it's just a structure representing a date and time. `ParseExact` is parsing your date string correctly.

If you want it formatted, you supply a format to `DateTime.ToString`, for example:

```
var formattedDate = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRy60W).

Comment: It would be better to use _proper_ culture settings like `InvariantCulture` since OP's `CurrentCulture` _might_ not use Gregorian Calendar as a `Calendar` property and/or _might_ have empty string as a time designators. In such cases, result will be different from what OP wants.

Comment: @SonerGönül fair point. Given the current output, I'd assumed the current culture was appropriate.

Comment: You have a point as well. But since we don't know _how_ OP generated this string representation (might use `CurrentCulture` or might not), I just wanna try to point :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.ParseExact` returns `DateTime` which doesn't have *any* implicit format. This "format" concept *only* applies when you get it's *textual* (a.k.a. `string`) representation.

You didn't told use how and where you see this `4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM` string but if you wanna get days part with leading zero, you can use [The `dd` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) with a *proper* culture (for calendar and time designators).

> The `dd` custom format string represents the day of the month as a
>   number from `01` through `31`. **A single-digit day is formatted with a
>   leading zero**.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20160416", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 04/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
```